Why is CORS blocking the GCF request when an ID is used?
I am making calls via the Hubspot API from a Firebase Cloud Functions file.  Most of these work without any issues; however, any endpoints that require an ID are blocked by CORS.  I've tested these endpoints using CURL and have received a response with no issue.  Below are 2 functions.  The first finds a contact by the email property and is working properly with no issues:
exports.getContactByEmail = withCorsAndHandler(async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const email = req.query.email;
  if (!email) {
    return res.status(400).send('Email address is required.');
  }
  await makeAxiosRequest(res, () => axiosInstance.get(`/crm/v3/objects/contacts/${email}?idProperty=email`));
});

The second is essentially the same request, however, the contact is identified by ID.
exports.getContactById = withCorsAndHandler(async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const contactId = req.query.contactId;
  if (!contactId) {
    return res.status(400).send('Contact ID is required.');
  }
  await makeAxiosRequest(res, () => axiosInstance.get(`/crm/v3/objects/contacts/${contactId}`));
});

With the getContactById() function, I receive the typical "blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error.
I'm not sure how this is possible since I have wrapped all of my CORS handling and middleware into previous, separate functions that clearly operate without any issues for non-contact ID driven requests.  For those of you who would like to see how this is setup:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');

// CORS Middleware
const corsHandler = cors({ origin: true });

// API keys from environment variables
const hubspotApiKey = functions.config().hubspot.api_key;

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.hubapi.com',
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${hubspotApiKey}` },
});

// Utility function to handle Axios requests
const makeAxiosRequest = async (res: any, axiosCall: any) => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosCall();
    res.status(200).send(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error with request to HubSpot:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error with request to HubSpot.");
  }
};

// Higher-order function to handle CORS and requests
const withCorsAndHandler = (handler: any) => {
  return functions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: any) => {
    corsHandler(req, res, () => {
      handler(req, res).catch((error: any) => {
        console.error("Error processing request:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
      });
    });
  });
};

Can anyone shed some light on why this might be happening?
